# Empty object in browser when returning JSONObject

Tags: java, json, rest

I have this method :

```
@GET
@Path("/myservice")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response mysercice() {

   boolean userExists = false;
   CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl();
   cacheControl.setNoCache(true);
   cacheControl.setNoStore(true);

   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
   jsonObject.put("userExists", userExists);
   return Response.ok(jsonObject, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).cacheControl(cacheControl).build();

}
```

When accessing to the URL of the method in the browser, I get { }, it means that the object is empty.
So, I tried to use :

```
return Response.ok(jsonObject.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).cacheControl(cacheControl).build();
```

So, I get in the browser {"userExists" : false}
**But I didn't understand why when returning simply the JSONObject, we get in the browser an empty object.**

Comment: because java objects are not stored as string so returning object and its string representation is entirely different thing.

Comment: Your browser doesn't know how your complex object is serialized - Java, .Net, Python.. So is your HTTP protocols. But they do understand string objects.

Comment: But in the code I have an example that returns a simple java object (all the attributes are String) and in this example, the object isn't empty in the browser. So, why is it empty in the case of JSONObject ?

Answer (score 2):

Most JAX-RS implementations come with a provider for mapping response entities to JSON. So when you write:

```
return Response.ok(jsonObject, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

You are basically requesting that the JAX-RS provider marshall the `JSONObject` into JSON for you. The only problem being that `JSONObject` isn't really meant to be serialized this way. Instead its meant to be used to build a JSON representation incrementally, then convert that representation into a JSON string value. You have two options:

1. Create a POJO containing all the fields you want to send back to the client. Return this POJO in your method and it will be automatically converted to JSON (`return Response.ok(myPojo, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build()
2. Return the JSON data directly as a String (which you already did in your example that works).