# JSONObject always returns "empty": false

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

There is a Spring Rest Controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("secanalytique")
public class SectionAnalytiqueController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/sectionbyaxepro/{codecomp}", produces = "application/json")
    public JSONObject getByAxePro(@PathVariable String codecomp) {
        JSONObject jsonModel = new JSONObject();
        jsonModel.put("cce0","frityyy");
        return jsonModel;
    }

}
```

I made a test with Postman : http://172.20.40.4:8080/Oxalys_WS/secanalytique/sectionbyaxepro/8 ; and what I got is always

```
{
    "empty": false
}
```

So what is wrong ?

Comment: can you add which library for JSONObject? is it org.json.simple.JSONObject?

Comment: it is from `org.json.JSONObject;` , dependency is : `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20180813</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: I am getting output as `{"cce0":"frityyy"}`, with simple.JSONObject

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941163/empty-object-in-browser-when-returning-jsonobject. 

I think you can try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14941402/6952155

Comment: Ohh, got it, when you add `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`, it converts object to Json, but since you already have json, which it tries to convert again, if you do `ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(jsonModel.toString())` `import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;`  or just `return jsonModel.toString();` it works

Comment: I would suggest define your own data type and you should not worry about json conversion, it will be taken care by Spring.

Answer (score 16):

I met same issue, and found the way to handle.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> getById(@PathVariable String id) {
    JSONObject jsObj = new JSONObject();
    jsObj.put("t0","test0");
    JSONArray jsArr = new JSONArray();
    jsArr.put(jsObj.toMap());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(jsObj.toMap(), HttpStatus.OK);
    //return new ResponseEntity<>(jsArr.toList(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: This solution is working fine. I wrap JSONObject in to an object like this  
`{"code": 200, "message": "success", "data": {JSONObject} }` . Use JSONObject.toMap() make the response produced as expected.

Answer (score 5):

There was one issue with your implementation that you are creating JSON object explicitly and returning it which is not required.
Instead, you should just send your java POJO/class, spring will convert it to JSON and return it.
Spring uses `Jackson` as the default serializer/deserializer.
Here since an object is already `JSONObject`, Jackson does not know how to serialize it.

There are two ways to solve this problem:

solution 1.
Define your own data type and populate it.

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

@GetMapping(value = "/sectionbyaxepro/{codecomp}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> getByAxePro(@PathVariable String codecomp) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("cce0","frityyy");
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(map);
}
```

OR

Solution 2.

Modify your existing code to either of the following ways.

1

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

@GetMapping(value = "/sectionbyaxepro/{codecomp}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> getByAxePro(@PathVariable String codecomp) {
    JSONObject jsonModel = new JSONObject();
    jsonModel.put("cce0","frityyy");
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(jsonModel.toString());
}
```

2

```
@GetMapping(value = "/sectionbyaxepro/{codecomp}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String getByAxePro(@PathVariable String codecomp) {
   JSONObject jsonModel = new JSONObject();
   jsonModel.put("cce0","frityyy");
   return jsonModel.toString();
}
```

Comment: Many many thanks, I was also facing a similar issue , tried the above approach and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

org.json.simple works. For somebody, who does not want to convert the result into String.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating JSONObject manually you can handle it in this way

```
@GetMapping(value = "/sectionbyaxepro/{codecomp}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getByAxePro(@PathVariable("codecomp") String codecomp){
        Map map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("key", "value");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: It will convert map to json automatically!